# null check operator used on a null value - MaterialApp

Tags: flutter

After the new upgrade of flutter to ">=2.7.0 <3.0.0", I am getting this error on the basic MaterialApp, which is in the main method. Actually, I build an app using getx state management, But later I decided to use provider, so I cleared all the code and started building from scratch, this is the following error I am getting

```
The following _CastError was thrown building Builder(dirty, dependencies: [MediaQuery]):

Null check operator used on a null value
```

and here is dart code

```
void main() async {
 runApp(MyApp());
 }
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return MaterialApp();
```

}
}

Comment: I am such a noob, got it solved by adding home property

Answer (score 0):

Try to add a child widget to your MaterialApp widget with a Scaffold and so on...that should work.

Something like this;

```
    void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      title: "I Love Flutter",
      theme: ThemeData(visualDensity: VisualDensity.adaptivePlatformDensity),
      home: MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}
```

and your HomePage ;

```
class MyHomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    Size _screenSize = MediaQuery.of(context).size;
    return SafeArea(
      child: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text("Just do it with Flutter :)"),
          centerTitle: true,
          elevation: 5,
        ),
        body: Container(
          width: _screenSize.width,
          height: _screenSize.height,
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            gradient: LinearGradient(
              begin: Alignment.topCenter,
              end: Alignment.bottomCenter,
              colors: [
                Colors.lightBlueAccent[100],
                Colors.lightBlueAccent[400],
                Colors.lightBlueAccent[700],
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```